# How to forcibly redirect a user on command and in real-time?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to create an admin feature that will allow an admin to destroy a user's session and redirect them to a new page in real time.

**For example:**

1. A user named Bob is active on the website, viewing a page.
2. An admin named Jill opens up a control panel and presses a button to forcibly log Bob out.
3. On the server, Bob's session is destroyed.
4. In Bob's browser **and in real time**, he is redirected to a page notifying him that he's been logged out.

I know how to remove Bob's session and force him to log back in when he goes to view a new page. But I do not know how to forcibly redirect Bob in real time. I'm guessing I need some kind of an active connection with Bob via Javascript so that I can push the command.

How would I do that? The only real-time Javascript knowledge I have is with AJAX, and that's usually triggered from the client-side and not the server-side.

I am using PHP 7.3 and CodeIgniter4 on the back-end. Currently no libraries on the front-end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use codeigniter 4 events. [EVENTS](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/extending/events.html)

```
use CodeIgniter\Events\Events;
```

From **admin side** you can trigger some events

```
\CodeIgniter\Events\Events::trigger('some_events', $foo, $bar, $baz);
```

and on **user side** you can use **on** to get that event

```
Events::on('some_event', function($foo, $bar, $baz) {
        ...
});
```

**Note** : codeigniter 4 is not ready for production yet.

Comment: It looks like this event system is used to gain better control of the CodeIgniter's execution process server-side. I do not see how this would solve the problem.

Comment: on backend side you can use this events for destroying session and redirection, if you want only on browser then i thing you need something like socket.io

Comment: I think so too, I just have no idea where to start and it feels like there's so many different possibilities that it's a little overwhelming at first. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I will try socket.io out and see if I can get it working.